# How can I send e-mails from my GMail account using REST service?

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api, gmail-imap, oauth2client

As of the end of May, 2022, Google no longer allows enabling "Less secure apps". So, I'm not able to use Basic authentication (i.e. user name and password) for sending e-mails using SMTP.

[The MailKit FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#gmail-access) is suggesting to use OAuth2, but when I implement the suggested code to my REST service, a browser opens at the web server (currently `localhost` as I'm still developing my REST service), displaying "Access blocked: This app's request is invalid":
[image: Google Redirect Error]

My REST service is supposed to run unattented. I won't be able to (a) enter any credentials, not (b) react to such visual error messages.

**How can I safely sent e-mails with my REST service using a GMail account?**