# How do I send e-mails using Google OAuth?

Tags: google-oauth

I want my .NET Web API service to convert a HTML user form data into an e-mail and send that e-mail using a GMail account that I created.

How would I do that?

I read through numerous [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) and [MailKit] documentations, but none is working for me: The Google documentation doesn't provide information on how unattended services access the Google API and the MailKit how-to [just doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76871274/how-can-i-send-e-mails-from-my-gmail-account-using-rest-service).

I need a comprehensive how-to guide:

1. Where in the Google Console do I have to create which kind of OAuth token?
2. What settings do I need to apply for it to work …

   1. locally
   2. on GitHub CI/CD
   3. on my public website

   … at the same time?
3. What `Google.Apis....` code do I need to program for this to work?

Your help is very much appreciated.